# Accordion - expand only by clicking on triangle

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to create accordion with  tabs,which expand/collapse only by clicking ui-triangle, not all ui-header. How i can do that?

My code

```
     $("#accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, heightStyle: "content", autoHeight: false, active: false, event: false });
     $(".ui-icon").live("click", function () {
                   //I need this code
                });
 $("#accordion").bind("accordionchangestart", function (event, ui) {});
```

Comment: provide a jsfiddle, maybe someone would be glad to help you